# How to create folder with files in project folder in visual studio code via AutoHotKey?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, autohotkey, windows-explorer

I created script via ahk that create folder with 2 files on shortcut when explorer is active.
Is it possible to run this script inside project explorer in visual studio code?

`````
#IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass
!1::openGui()

openGui() {
    Js := "import styled from 'styled-components';`n`nexport const Wrapper = styled.div````;"
    WinGetActiveTitle, MyWin
    Gui, New
    InputBox, Name, Input folder name
    if ErrorLevel
    return
    else
        Jsx =   
    ( 
import React from 'react';
import { Wrapper } from './%Name%.styles';

const %Name% = () => {
    return <Wrapper>%Name%</Wrapper>;
}; 
    
export default %Name%;
)
    FileCreateDir, %MyWin%\%Name%
    FileAppend, %Jsx%, %MyWin%\%Name%\%Name%.jsx
    FileAppend, %Js%, %MyWin%\%Name%\%Name%.styles.js
}
return
`````

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you started script manually and it's running in the tray,

[image]

using ahk Window Spy you can verify vs studio window value to be `ahk_exe devenv.exe`

so you can use for example `if WinExist("ahk_exe devenv.exe")` instead `#IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass` which is to detect windows explorer window not vs studio.

in summary:

`````
if WinExist("ahk_exe devenv.exe")
!1::openGui()


openGui() {
    Js := "import styled from 'styled-components';`n`nexport const Wrapper = styled.div````;"
    WinGetActiveTitle, MyWin
    Gui, New
    InputBox, Name, Input folder name
    if ErrorLevel
    return
    else
        Jsx =   
    ( 
import React from 'react';
import { Wrapper } from './%Name%.styles';

const %Name% = () => {
    return <Wrapper>%Name%</Wrapper>;
}; 
    
export default %Name%;
)
    FileCreateDir, %MyWin%\%Name%
    FileAppend, %Jsx%, %MyWin%\%Name%\%Name%.jsx
    FileAppend, %Js%, %MyWin%\%Name%\%Name%.styles.js
}
return
`````

now when i press `alt  + 1` i can create folder.

[image]